# Change table view cell upon selection?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView a bit like the iPhone Mail app's in box. This includes the blue dot indicating the message is unread. How would set this image to hidden upon selection.. ?

There doesn't seem to be any way to refer to the cell within the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```